# How to combine two lists, remove duplicates, without changing element order of the lists?

Tags: python, list

I want to combine two lists and remove duplicate values.

Suppose I have two lists:

```
lst1 = [23,15,46,76,45]
lst2 = [43,32,15,49,45,10]
```

I want to output:

```
result = [23,15,46,76,45,43,32,49,10]
```

In the result, the list order of the elements must be maintained. For example, in the second list, element 43 at position 0, then after that 32 came in, then after that 49 came, then after that 10 came and so on...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set`:

```
In [1]: set(lst1).union(set(lst2))
Out[1]: {10, 15, 23, 32, 43, 45, 46, 49, 76}
```

If the order is important you can use this:

```
resulting_list = lst1
resulting_list.extend(x for x in lst2 if x not in resulting_list)
```

Output:

> [23, 15, 46, 76, 45, 43, 32, 49, 10]

Comment: Using a set will not preserve the order of the elements.

Comment: I don't think this is guaranteed to preserve the order.

Comment: I changed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the elements that aren't already in the first list, from the second:

```
for element in list_2:
    if element not in list_1:
        list_1.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the order of the list, maybe you can try:

```
set(lst1).union(set(lst2))
```

And you can get a set `{32, 10, 43, 76, 45, 46, 15, 49, 23}`.

If you want to keep the order of the list, you can try this:

```
print(lst1+[i for i in lst2 if i not in lst1])
```

Output:

```
[23, 15, 46, 76, 45, 43, 32, 49, 10]
```

If there may be duplicate elements in `lst1` and `lst2`,example:

```
lst1 = [1,2,1,3]
lst2 = [2,4,5,4]
```

And you still want to keep the order of these two lists, you can remove the duplicate elements and then combine them:

```
ts = set()
rm_duplicate=lambda l:[x for x in l if not (x in ts or ts.add(x))]

print(rm_duplicate(lst1)+[i for i in rm_duplicate(lst2) if i not in lst1])
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: yay quadratic time!

Comment: >>`set(lst1).union(set(lst2))` 
the same as `set(lst1+lst2)` !?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = lst1 + [element for element in lst2 if element not in lst1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list elements are hashable:

```
st1 = set(lst1)
result = lst1 + [i for i in lst2 if not i in st1]
```

In your toy example you won't feel the difference but if the lists are moderately large converting to set will speed up element lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set like this,

```
lst1 = [23,15,46,76,45]
lst2 = [43,32,15,49,45,10]

print list(set(lst1 + lst2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Python has a built-in `set` [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) that does this type of operation:

`set(lst1).union(set(lst2))`

Comment: `set(lst1+lst2)` !?