# How to find the solution list with python string list manipulation

Tags: python, string, list

I am looking for a way to find the expected output:
Here we have both list contains strings. Please take a look at below input lists:

```
lst1 =["a: ","b: ","c:","d :"]
lst2 =[" b:"," a:","f:","g:","c: ","d:"]
```

Expected:

```
outputlst=["a: ","b: ","c:","d :",f:","g:"]
```

Here `outputlst` will always have `lst1` elements whereas their similar lst2 variations "a: "," b: ","c:", "d:" must be removed.
I have not reached results so far with list iterations versions.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two lists, remove duplicates, without changing element order of the lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324940/how-to-combine-two-lists-remove-duplicates-without-changing-element-order-of-t)

Comment: A simplistic algorithm might be:- copy lst1 to outputlst. Iterate over lst2, strip each element, check if stripped value exists in outputlst and if not, append it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend using `outputlst = list(set(lst1 + lst2))` but since there's a slight variation by whitespaces in two ends, you can probably create a list or set (`already_contained` in below code) to check if a string with trailing whitespaces removed and use it as a check to see if a string in `lst2` should be passed to `outputlst`

```
lst1 =["a: ","b: ","c:"]
lst2 =[" b:"," a:","f:","g:","c: "]
already_contained = set([c.replace(':', '').strip() for c in lst1])
outputlst = lst1 + [c for c in lst2 if c.replace(':', '').strip() not in already_contained]
```

Comment: Appreciate your thought could u please try it for lst1 =["a: ","b: ","c:","d :"]
lst2 =[" b:"," a:","f:","g:","c: ","d:"] i tried but we are not getting output is as expected. Please check the new input i included in question summary. Here in output "d" is including from both lists

Comment: @PiyushS. I wasn't aware that there could be spaces between character and `:`. I've updated my post to take that into account

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation I learn a lot from you. It's working fine. Appreciate your explanation with solution.